# Can I use javascript to make the equivalent of Windows Form Applications?

Tags: javascript, windows

I have used Visual Studio to make Windows forms applications using C# and VB but I would like to start learning another language, preferably javascript. Can I do this? I just downloaded Visual Studio 2012 Professional and the only option I can find is to make Windows 8 Apps.

Sorry if this is an obvious question with an obvious answer but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Also I'm interested if my line of thought (trying to use javascript to make windows desktop applications) is a dumb one so please chime in if it is.

Thanks!

I should point out I will be developing a UI that cannot be run from a browser necessarily; that is technicians will be using it in the field, far away from wifi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 8 supports *desktop* applications written in Javascript. Previous versions of Windows don't... at least not inherently.

I'd suggest, given that this is an introduction to Javascript... and that Windows 8 desktop apps work in a similar fashion to web pages, that you focus in on constructing regular web pages that contain Javascript.

This can be achieved by creating a plain old HTML file (with any editor ... including Visual Studio) and loading it up into a web browser.

Once you're across how Javascript works in a regular web settings, it should be easier to tackle everything from Windows 8 apps through to ChromiumEmbedded apps.

Comment: I'd need something for cross-platform, or at least for multiple versions of Windows.

Comment: @tmwoods: Webs are cross-platform by nature, Izcd has good advice. I'd start building a very simple web app that runs on the browser and then move in into NodeJS for desktop apps.

Comment: I'm going to be connected to a device for this application; can I do this through a web application? It's for a data acquisition device (i.e. mass data transfer, graphing, statistics, analytics, etc.)

Comment: If it's just multiple versions of windows, I'd suggest creating a "wrapper" application in your choice of "native" language and platform (e.g. C#, Winforms, WPF) which does nothing except load up a script and display it in a browser control. This will provide all the advantages of web display technologies but still allow you to deploy as a standard win app. The only down side is that you'll need to write the "bridging" code between JS and any operating system functionality yourself.

Comment: Alternatively there are third party that supply the wrapping and bridging code... but obviously can only provide functionality that they've specifically catered for.

Comment: @lzcd I'm not sure my skillset is expansive enough to accomplish that. The reason I am switching is because I ran into a hardware incompatibility issue with the .NET serialport class (it's a known bug) which is why I am switching in the first place.

Comment: Be aware that Javascript has traditionally been centered around web related stuff so there's no device communications packages (as it would pose a security risk for regular web use). As such you're probably up for supplying the bridging code between JS and the device yourself. It probably wouldn't be the first approach I'd suggest but if it's a educational exercise, there's no harm in learning.

Comment: My alternative choice right now is using QT. Is that a good idea do you reckon?

Comment: If .Net had issues for you then I suspect Javascript is going to place you even further away from solving your problem. I'd suggest instead opting for another "native"  / non-web solution such as Python, Ruby or Go.

Comment: I have no useful opinion to give on QT.

Comment: Okey dokey. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

It's not dumb - JavaScript lends itself well to GUI programming. It's not WinForms, but there are bindings of node.js to QT, for example. https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write an [**HTML Application**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx), which is web app that runs locally and with the same rights as any compiled application.  These have been around since at least Windows 95 and are still supported in Windows 8.

To create an HTML Application, save your HTML file with an HTA extension.  It will run just like any other web app, but without the security restrictions.  For example, you will have access to the file system.  Instead of running in a browser, it has its own window and icon, both of which are customizable via the [`<hta:application>` tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536495.aspx):

```
<hta:application id="MyApp"
    icon="MyApp.ico"
    border="none"
    windowstate="maximize" />
```

Make sure to include an `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag, lest your code be run in IE7 mode:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

For deployment, create an installer using your favorite method, or just zip up all files needed, and have users unzip to any directory on their computer and create shortcuts on the desktop or in the start menu as needed.

All the information you need to get started is [in the documentation at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx).

[**JScript.Net**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72bd815a.aspx) is another option.  This implementation (and extension) of JavaScript, allows you to actually write Windows Forms applications with JavaScript.  Sadly, there's no IDE support that I know of. The last (and maybe only) version of Visual Studio to support JScript.Net was Visual Studio 2005.  You would have to write the code without the help of an IDE and use the command line compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is the web world, you're not restricted to Windows forms, all you need is HTML, CSS, JavaScript and an embedded browser, like [chromiumembedded](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) (has .NET bindings) or [App.js](http://appjs.org/) for [Node](http://nodejs.org/) which I think uses CEF as well.

There also many frameworks that provide UI elements, like jQuery UI, Extjs and many more.

Comment: Does that mean my application would run in Chrome or a web browser? I need something that looks professional and preferably standalone.

Answer (score 0):

You can build JavaScript applications that "look like" a Windows application using Visual Studio. But you should realize that this application will almost certainly be a Web-Application that will have to be hosted on a server and will run in a Browser.

So my advice if you want to learn is to look into Web-applications using Visual Studio first to understand how the application is structured. Javascrip apps can be debugged and written in Visual Studio and if they are well designed they can look and feel just like a Windows application, but with many advantages, mainly that users do not need to install it on their computers.

Comment: Apologies, I only saw now that you specifically want a desktop application without wifi. So my answer does not apply (would delete if if I could!).