# Does Nodejs have any framework/lib that support creating winform?

Tags: node.js, winforms

I was wondering is there an lib to help us create winform in GUI programming for Windows operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge)

> Run .NET and Node.js code in-process on Windows, MacOS, and Linux

Additionally, have a look at this SO post

- [Can I use javascript to make the equivalent of Windows Form Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15374786/16471349)

Comment: Thank you, I have found this one: https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt